# Modify Jackson responce for pagination on Extjs grid using @ResponseBody

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have class User:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    .....
}
```

And have controller method:

```
@RequestMapping ...
@ResponseBody public List<User> loadAll(...) {
    List<User> users = ...;
    return users;
}
```

Now json looks like:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Michael"},{"id":2,"name":"Peter"},...]
```

and all works fine, but I wan to add pagination. How json should look like:

```
["users":[{"id":1,"name":"Michael"},{"id":2,"name":"Peter"},...],"totalCount":500 ]
```

And I am trying to find best practice to do this modifications.

**Spring version: 3.1.2.RELEASE**

Thanks

PS.I am new to Jackson. I used net.sf.json but do not want to fully generate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with a `HashMap`. Something like this :

```
@RequestMapping ...
@ResponseBody public Map<String, Object> loadAll(...) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<User> users = ...;

    response.put("users", users);
    response.put("totalCount", 500);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Great tricks! I expected something like ten lines of xml and two classes of java code.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the list of users in a view object like so:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public @ResponseBody Users loadAll() {
    int totalCount = ...;
    List<User> list = ...;
    return new Users(totalCount, list);
}

...

final class Users {
    public final int totalCount;
    public final List<User> users;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jukka. I think your solution is working but accepted solution more beautiful and correct